# DatabaseCleaner not working with Capybara automated tests

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

I'm running automated tests using Capybara and Poltergeist on a Rails site that runs on MySQL.

I see where it commits the "data" inserts when running this automated suite but DatabaseCleaner seems to do nothing, I get no errors when running it at all either.

(I made sure gems are installed as well). This is my first run with DatabaseCleaner, but nothing seems to be working.

Relevant portion of rails_helper file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

     config.before(:suite) do
          DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
     end

     config.before(:each) do
          DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
     end

     config.before(:each, :js => true) do
          DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
     end

     config.before(:each) do
          DatabaseCleaner.start
     end

     config.after(:each) do
          DatabaseCleaner.clean
     end
end
```

Also, I made sure `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`.

My test_helper.rb file is nothing fancy either:

```
#Load up Capybara/Rspec
require 'rails_helper'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'    

#Load up Poltergeist
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

#Set JS Supported Driver
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

And finally a sample script, which basically goes through a locally run Rails website and creates a record. It's simple, but I'm just using this as an example. The automated tests all do their thing.

```
require 'test_helper'
describe  "Test", :type => :feature, :js => true do
  it 'Add Widget' do
    visit ('/')
    fill_in('user_email', :with => 'test@test.com')
    fill_in('user_password', :with => 'p@ssword')
    click_button('Log in')
    click_link('Tools')
    expect(page).to have_content 'Tools'
    click_link('Stuff')
    expect(page).to have_content 'Stuff'
    click_link('Create New Thingy')
    expect(page).to have_content 'New Thingy'
    fill_in('thingy_name', :with => 'Name for a Thing!')
    click_button('Create Thing!')
  end
end
```

Am I missing something here? I don't get any errors when running, but the data just doesn't get deleted.

I'm running MySQL 5.6.26 and Rails 4.0.2.

Comment: If you don't see any rollbacks or truncations, sounds like the `DatabaseCleaner` configuration never happens - could you add some `puts` debug messages to the before / after blocks and see if they are run at all? Also I notice that you require 'rspec' after 'rails_helper', i.e. after you've already configured RSpec. While this probably is not the source of the problem, I'd still try to clean up the requires (most of them should be done already from the Gemfile) or move the rails_helper require down a bit.

Comment: You see your test hits a locally running rails app do you mean the app is running via `rails s`, and you've configured capybara to point to that port?

Comment: @FrederickCheung that is correct

Comment: Where have you put `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`? Have you asserted the config block is being called at the proper moment? Also, try to test database cleaner directly in your test description or console to validate it's  working.

Comment: it's in the rails_helper.rb file. I confirmed it was false. Testing it in the console is a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, database_cleaner will clean the test database for the app whose tests are being run. If the requests in your integration spec are going to some other app, not running against this test database, then it will do nothing to that other database (it doesn't even know it exists).

You can give database cleaner extra databases to clean. If your database.yml listed the details for this other db with the key `:integration`, ie it contained something like

```
integration:
  adapter: mysql
  database: some_db
  ...
```

Then you could use

```
DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, { :connection => :integration }].strategy = :truncation
```

To specify that this database should also be truncated when calling  `DatabaseCleaner.clean`. This will of course delete *everything* from that database on each test run.

Comment: I guess how can I tell if it's actually targeting my database? the app is pretty simple as far as configuration w/the database. It's just a sqlite db that I run it with.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Maybe im a bit confused at what you are saying I should do? I don't understand what you are meaning by the :Integration key

Comment: You need to tell database_cleaner where this SQLite db is. The easiest way to do that is to add the details of that db to database.yml (in the app where the tests are) under some key (I've used integration - doesn't matter what it is as long as it matches what you tell database cleaner to use

Comment: Ah gotcha, yeah the db is in database.yml but I didn't realize you needed some key to match database cleaner up with the database.yml, i'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to work, so im marking this answer correct

Answer (score 1):

Debugging tip:  Turn on the "general log" in MySQL to see what queries, *if any* are being performed.  With luck, that will give you a clue of what part of the test harness to stare at.

Comment: Rick, if you have time, your presence is requested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37818604) ... thanks. Will clean up this message later.

Comment: That is one thing I did check, the insert queries are happening, but no kind of rollback or anything besides that